# echo $DOM->saveXML() safety (htmlspecialchars)

Tags: php, xml, htmlspecialchars

Have following code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');

$root = $dom->createElement('корневой');
$dom->appendChild($root);

$data = [
    ['TransactionPartnerName' => 'Transaction-Partner-Name-1'],
];

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $child11 = $dom->createElement('вложенный', $row['TransactionPartnerName'] );
    $root->appendChild($child11);

    $child_att11 = $dom->createAttribute('vārds');
    $child11->appendChild($child_att11);

    $att_text11 = $dom->createTextNode('Value attribute11');
    $child_att11->appendChild($att_text11);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

When I see `echo` and variable, always want to use `htmlspecialchars`. None of following works: `echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML(), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`, `echo htmlspecialchars($dom, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")->saveXML()`.

Tried to replace `($row['TransactionPartnerName'])` with for example `<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>` (inserted in mysql). In output I do not see hyperlink, see simple `<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>`.

So question. Is `htmlspecialchars` required somewhere? May be to use here `(htmlspecialchars(($row['TransactionPartnerName']), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") )`?

Comment: `foreach ($data as $row) {` : What's `$data` here?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky `$data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Rest assured that both http://php.net/htmlspecialchars and http://php.net/domdocument.savexml do just work properly. So what is your concrete question? You can not just create a question and say it does not work without even telling exactly what you expect it to do and what it does instead. Also your example you need to create from scratch containing as little code and data as necessary and self-containing so that it is easy to reproduce your problem with it. In it's current form, the example is not of much help.

Comment: I exemplarily edited your code to show that a little better. It is so, that it does now work, see here: https://eval.in/private/af772254ed7ee8 - But the question remains, where your concrete problem arises and what it actually is.

Comment: @hakre I worry if my code is/not hole for XSS. As know to prevent, must use `htmlspecialchars`. Question is if in that code need to use `htmlspecialchars`. If need, then where.

Comment: Thanks for edit. Main aim is to remove any security holes.